# Can't get the Highcharts x-axis date to work

Tags: php, json, date, highcharts

I have searched the high and low in Stackoverflow for a fix on this date problem. I'm really struggling to get the date to display on the chart with the points being correctly set onto them.

Here is the JS Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                            var options = {
                                chart: {
                                        renderTo: 'drawing',
                                        zoomType: 'x',
                                        width: 900,
                                        height: 222
                                    },
                                    exporting: {
                                      enabled: true      
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: url+' - '+keyword
                                    },
                                    credits: {
                                        text: 'Testing',
                                        href: ''
                                    },
                                    xAxis: {
                                        type: 'datetime'
                                    },
                                    yAxis: [{
                                        allowDecimals: false,
                                        reversed: true,
                                        title: {
                                            text: 'Rankings'
                                        }
                                    },],
                                    tooltip: {
                                        crosshairs: true,
                                        shared: true
                                    },
                                    series: [{}]
                            };  

                                var url =  "****/chart.php";
                                $.getJSON(url,  function(data1){                            

                                options.series = data1;
                                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                            });                          
                        });
```

This is what our PHP Script Generated for the JSON

```
[{"name":"Google Rank","data":[["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 08)",23],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 05)",24],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 04)",23],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 03)",22],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 02)",24],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 01)",26],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 31)",24],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 30)",24],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 29)",25],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 28)",25],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 27)",25],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 26)",26],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 25)",25],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 24)",24],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 23)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 22)",10],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 21)",10],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 20)",10],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 19)",10],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 18)",10],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 17)",10],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 16)",9],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 15)",9],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 14)",9],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 13)",9]],"visible":true,"pointInterval":86400000,"showInLegend":true},{"name":"Bing Rank","data":[["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 08)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 05)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 04)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 03)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 02)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 01)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 31)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 30)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 29)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 28)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 27)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 26)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 25)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 24)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 23)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 22)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 21)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 20)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 19)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 18)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 17)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 16)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 15)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 14)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 13)",0]],"visible":true,"pointInterval":86400000,"showInLegend":true},{"name":"Yahoo Rank","data":[["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 08)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 05)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 04)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 03)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 02)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 01)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 31)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 30)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 29)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 28)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 27)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 26)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 25)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 24)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 23)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 22)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 21)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 20)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 19)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 18)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 17)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 16)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 15)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 14)",0],["Date.UTC(2013, 2, 13)",0]],"visible":true,"pointInterval":86400000,"showInLegend":true}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSON you cannot use functions like Date.UTC(), so I advice to use timestamp number.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. Firstly, I have changed it so they now give out timestamps but the chart shows the "TIME" for example: 18:40, 18:45, 18:50, 18:55 and so on.. Then when I go to hover over each point, I can only view the first and last point..

Comment: Have you sorted data by x, ascending ?

Comment: I'm not really sure.. The code above with the JS is still the same as it is now so.

Comment: ["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 08)",23],["Date.UTC(2013, 3, 05)",24 it looks like not sorted asceding.

Comment: Okay. I have changed that to ascending. The points now work however, the X-Axis still show TIME rather than date? It stays on the same day too?

Comment: You can define it in http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. I have adjusted the JS code to the following: 
                                            type: 'datetime',
                                            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                                            month: '%b \'%y'
                                            } and it still doesn't show it correctly.

Comment: Well, it strange, but you can also use formatter ( http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter) and return date by (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#highcharts.dateFormat()) In case when you cannot achive appropriate effect, please reproduce whole chart in the jsfiddle.net

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to get it to display on JSFiddle, not sure why. The Highcharts.com website seems to be offline.

Comment: Indeed we have small problem with server, but you can try to update this example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/7A9Hv/1/

Comment: You should multiply all timestamps by 1000, to adapt it to JS timestamp format. Updated example with one correct serie http://jsfiddle.net/7A9Hv/3/